# PHP won't loop though a text file

Tags: php

I'm having trouble trying to get php to loop though a text file so it will download all the links from inside the text file, the first file will download fine but then it stops, if anyone is able to help I would really appreciate it, thank you very much.

```
<?php
$file_handle = fopen("list.txt", "r"); 
$lineCount=0;
$line = array();

while (!feof($file_handle)) {
array_push($line, fgets($file_handle));
$lineCount++;
}

for($i=0;$i<$lineCount;$i++){

set_time_limit (24 * 60 * 60);

$destination_folder = 'files/';

$newfname = $destination_folder . basename($line[$i]);

$file = fopen ($line[$i], "rb");
if ($file) {
    $newf = fopen ($newfname, "wb");

    if ($newf){
        while(!feof($file)) {
             fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
        }
    }
}

echo $line[$i].'...done.<br />';

if ($file) {
    fclose($file);
}

if ($newf) {
    fclose($newf);
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping everything you want the for loop to repeat in {}

```
$file_handle = fopen("list.txt", "r");
$lineCount=0;
$line = array();

while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    array_push($line, fgets($file_handle));
    $lineCount++;
}

for($i=0;$i<$lineCount;$i++){

    set_time_limit (24 * 60 * 60);

    $destination_folder = 'files/';

    $newfname = $destination_folder . basename($line[$i]);

    $file = fopen ($line[$i], "rb");
    if ($file) {
        $newf = fopen ($newfname, "wb");

        if ($newf){
            while(!feof($file)) {
                 fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
            }
        }
    }

    echo $line[$i].'...done.<br />';

    if ($file) {
        fclose($file);
    }

    if ($newf) {
        fclose($newf);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work, only one file downloads

Comment: I have made an edit, adding in a line counter, give that a try.

Comment: I'm rather baffled as it's still only downloading the first file, but this time it echo's out the url for the first file three times (there are three file url's in the text file)

Comment: Another edit, this time pushing into an array to keep track of each line.

Comment: The file on line three in the text file downloads, but the files on line one and two report these errors, Warning: fopen failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found on line 19, Notice: Undefined variable: newf on line 36

Comment: Can you paste here the contents of the text file, flying blind here :)

Comment: http://www.freesmileys.org/smileys/smiley-cool05.gif
http://www.freesmileys.org/smileys/smiley-cool11.gif
http://www.freesmileys.org/smileys/smiley-cool15.gif :)

Comment: I've spent three hours trying to get it to work correctly but I'm still hitting a brick wall :(

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get "lineCount" through while loop but the "$line" variable will be overwritten.

Declare $line as array above while loop and then add file names in it. Use below code.

```
$file_handle = fopen("list.txt", "r");
$lineCount=0;
$line = array();
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $strmTemp = trim(fgets($file_handle));
    if (strlen($strmTemp) > 0)
    {
        $line[] = $strmTemp;
        $lineCount++;
    }
}

for($i=0;$i<$lineCount;$i++){

    set_time_limit (24 * 60 * 60);

    $destination_folder = 'files/';

    $newfname = $destination_folder . basename($line[$lineCount]);

    $file = fopen ($line[$lineCount], "rb");
    if ($file) {
        $newf = fopen ($newfname, "wb");

        if ($newf){
            while(!feof($file)) {
                 fwrite($newf, fread($file, 1024 * 8 ), 1024 * 8 );
            }
        }
    }

    echo $line[$lineCount].'...done.<br />';

    if ($file) {
        fclose($file);
    }

    if ($newf) {
        fclose($newf);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get three notice and one warning error looped three times, Notice: Undefined offset: 3 on line 16, Notice: Undefined offset: 3 on line 18, Warning: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty on line 18, Notice: Undefined offset: 3 on line 29

Comment: Try printing $line[$lineCount], it seems that there are some empty line. may be at end of file. In while loop check values of fgets($file_handle) is not blank. Modified my code.

Comment: With the updated code it's down to one error, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'strlen' (T_STRING), expecting '(' on line 7, I can't see where "(" could be missing from

Comment: I'm not sure what happened but the updated code caused firefox to crash.

Comment: With the edited code these errors are displayed, Notice: Use of undefined constant strmTemp - assumed 'strmTemp' on line 9, Notice: Undefined offset: 3 on line 20, Notice: Undefined offset: 3 on line 22, Warning: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty on line 22, Notice: Undefined offset: 3 on line 33, Notice: Undefined variable: newf on line 39

Comment: I think you have not picked the latest one. can you try one more time. it is working fine at my end.

Comment: That's strange as I've double checked and it's the latest edit and I'm still getting the same errors

Comment: Please check line 9 is "$line[] = $strmTemp;" not "$line[] = strmTemp;".

Comment: It's "$line[] = $strmTemp;"

Answer (score 0):

If the list.txt file isn't large you could use file() to read it:

```
$urls = file('list.txt');
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    // Do download and save logic here
}
```